# Unchecking of the checked checkboxes on another button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want the checked checkboxes to be unchecked when clicking another button:

Below is the **HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkb" id="Agent" value="Agent"> type=Agent
<br />

  <input type="checkbox" name="checkb" id="Customer" value="Customer"> type=Customer
<br />

  <input type="checkbox" name="checkb" id="Phone" value="Phone"> type=Phone
<br />

  <input type="checkbox" name="checkb" id="ID_Card" value="ID_Card"> type=ID_Card
<br />

<input type=datetime id="Start_Date" value="" placeholder="Start_Date" />
<input type=datetime id="End_Date" value="" placeholder="End_Date" />
<button id="date">
  Interval
</button>
```

On clicking of the **Interva**l button if any checkboxes are checked they should get unchecked.

Below is the **event listener** for the **Interval** button:

```
var check1 = document.getElementById("Agent");
var check2 = document.getElementById("Customer");
var check3 = document.getElementById("Phone");
var check4 = document.getElementById("ID_Card");

var newBtn = document.getElementById("date");
if (newBtn) {
  newBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

    if (check1.checked) {
      var ischecked1 = check1.checked;

      check1.checked != ischecked1;
    }
    if (check2.checked) {
      var ischecked2 = check2.checked;

      check2.checked != ischecked2;

    }

    if (check3.checked) {
      var ischecked3 = check3.checked;

      check3.checked != ischecked3;
    }
    if (check4.checked) {
      var ischecked4 = check4.checked;

      check4.checked != ischecked4;

    }
  });
}
```

Below code runs without any errors, but the boxes do not get unchecked if they are checked.

Below is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/aed0yzjy/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statements are just evaluating as booleans, not performing assignments:

```
check1.checked != ischecked1; // this returns a boolean, doesn't do any assignment
```

You want to do this to toggle the checked state:

```
check1.checked = !ischecked1;
```

Same thing for other checkboxes.

There's also no need to create the extra variables, you can just do the toggling and reading directly:

```
check1.checked = !check1.checked;
```

Since you're only toggling checkboxes when they are checked, you can just directly set them to `false` as well.

```
if (check1.checked) check1.checked = false;
```

Instead of having `if` statements, you can use array iteration to do the toggling:

```
[check1, check2, check3, check4].forEach(check => {
  if (check.checked) {
    check.checked = false;
  }
});

// or query the checkboxes directly and do the same
[...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')].forEach(check => {
  if (check.checked) {
    check.checked = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: worth noting, but not worth answering with that this is perfect and could also be improved if placed in some sort of each loop with a class specifically associated to this group or use the name of the checks. But great answer.

Comment: when I try locally and not in the jsfiddle it fails with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
    at forEach.check (http://172.31.179.196:5000/static/final.js:457:18)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onSelectChange

Comment: That's because one of the elements is `null`, meaning you either put the wrong id into `getElementById` so it couldn't find an element or you put the right id but forgot to add the element to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it you just want to uncheck everything on click of button

you can just do this

```
var newBtn = document.getElementById("date");
if (newBtn) {
    newBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementById("Agent").checked =   
      document.getElementById("Customer").checked =
      document.getElementById("Phone").checked =
      document.getElementById("ID_Card").checked = false;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
check1.checked != ischecked1;
```

This actually means "compare if check1.checked is not equal to ischecked1".

Most simple solution would be to remove the if statement and just do this:

```
check1.checked = !check1.checked
```

This means "set check1.checked to the opposite of check1.checked".

Since all checkboxes have the same name you could also collect all checkboxes by requesting them by name and use a loop to walk through them. A small example:

```
// Collect all checkboxes with a CSS selector that matches all input
// elements with a name attribute that's equal to "checkb"
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkb"]');

var newBtn = document.getElementById("date");
if (newBtn) {
  newBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // this is a for loop, it will run for as long as i
    // is smaller than the amount of found checkboxes (checkboxes.length)
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      // Get the checkbox from the checkboxes collection
      // collection[i] means get item from collection with index i
      var checkbox = checkboxes[i];

      // Revert the .checked property of the checkbox
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    }
  });
}
```